# Sharing Keychain data between app and extension

Tags: swift, keychain

I am not able to get data in extension using Keychain Access.

**What did I do ?**

1. I have enabled the keychchain sharing capabilities in both the targets and gave the same identifier.
2. I have initialized the Keychain like this:

   `static let keychain = Keychain(service: "teamID.com.appname.ios.sharedKeychain", accessGroup: "teamID.com.appname.ios.sharedKeychain")`

I have also tried with just service/access group while initializing.

**Error in extension ?**

> OSStatus error:[-25291] No keychain is available. You may need to
>   restart your computer.

Xcode 11.3.1, Swift: 5

What is the problem in this approach ? There are many questions regarding sharing data between App and extension but still I am not able to find what's missing.

**Note**: This code works well on simulator. 
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're using the iCloud keychain or not. But, if you are then the user must be linked to an iCloud account to use the keychain. Also, I think there is a permission they have to accept (not positive about that one though).

Comment: @stuckj Thanks for the input. But no I am not using iCloud. I am trying to share data using Keychain acess groups.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood me. I'm not talking about using iCloud directly. I mean using keychain with the kSecAttrSynchronizable attribute (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecattrsynchronizable?language=objc). That enables synchronization of keychain via iCloud. If the user doesn't have iCloud enabled I believe storing to keychain will fail if you enable synchronization. If you're using a library for keychain it may have a different parameter name for whether or not it's using keychain with iCloud.

Comment: @stuckj I am confused now. But thanks, I will be looking into this more. Just one thing that keychain is working fine for main app, it's just the extension. It is not performing any keychain related operation in that. I have open access enabled too. Is it something related to using same pod in both the targets ? 

Also I have checked, kSecAttrSynchronizable, it is by default false for the library, so its not using iCloud Sync.

Comment: My mistake, all this time I thought I have allowed the `Allow Full Access` from Keyboard settings in my device. Turning it on resolved everything as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127443/access-the-keychain-from-ios-keyboard-extension

Comment: Cool, glad you got it sorted.